# how to wrap text in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, jgraph, mxgraph

So I'm rendering some objects with specific `width` of 120px and the objects will have different titles. My problem is when the title is too long it doesn't wrap it and put it in a new line. Is there a work-around this kind of issue in svg?

```
var labels = ["Testing 123", "Things are fantastic"]

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
            {
                cell = editor.graph.cloneCells([cell])[0];
                // cell.setStyle(new-style);
                editor.graph.model.valueForCellChanged(cell, label);

                editor.toolbar.addPrototype(label, "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='43px' width='104px'>" +
                    "<rect fill='#595A5A' stroke='black' x='0' y='0' rx='5' ry='5' width='100%' height='100%'/>"+
                    "<text text-anchor='middle' font-weight='600' font-family='Helvetica' fill='#BCCF00' x='50%' y='25' font-size='12'>" + label + "</text></svg>", cell);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic text wrapping in SVG 1.1. You need to layout your text into lines yourself.

Comment: Are you confirming that even in normal svg, we cant break line; Is there possibility of putting the text tag in a box which could contain the text, instead of hide the overflowed

Comment: Generic SVG 1.1 has no wrapping ability. That is likely to change in SVG 2 when it is released. However, if you are in a browser, you can make use of the `<foreignObject>` element to [embed HTML inside your SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). That is your only option.